# Разбиение текста на строки (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, строки

Недавно пришлось написать функцию, которая делает следующее: дан текст, функция преобразовывает его так, чтобы длины всех строк не привышали заданное число, если же какая-нибудь строка превышает, то её необходимо разбить на несколько, длины которых не привышают это число.

Появился вопрос, есть ли в .NET такая функция?

Comment: P.S. Я имею ввиду не используя регулярки, т.е. функция на подобии String.Split("...");<br /><br /> Если у вас есть проблема и вы думаете решить её с помощью регулярок, то у вас две проблемы :)

Comment: регулярки? 2е проблемы? а как ты это хочешь по другому? можешь брать весь массив, проходить по нему, счетчиком считать нужное количество букв, копировать их в другое место, копировать оставшиеся, вставлять..

Comment: "Ёу, чувак"...<br />
Я ж сказал (см. коммент на ваш ответ), мне не нужна реализация, тем более способы реализации, мне нужно узнать СУЩЕСТВУЕТ ЛИ ФУНЦИЯ, которая вернёт массив искомых строк...<br />
Моя самописная функция регулярками и парсит!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то у тебя все сложно, имхо, если тебе надо на форме ограничить текст - ограничь сразу текстБокс, а если тебе надо нарезать его то пользуйся substring()-ом на нужную длину, "запоминай" то что осталось и выводи в нужное место

Comment: Должно быть так: я вызвал эту функцию, а она мне вернула массив строк как String.Split().<br />
Как такую фунцию реализовать способов я знаю под мильён, вопрос не состоит в проблеме разбиения текста на строки, а в существовании оной функции.

Comment: ты делаешь искусственную проблему, врятли именно такая есть в стандартных библиотеках, но если ее реализация - 3 строчки, что тут можно выяснять?))

Comment: @Gorets, 
Как бы никакую проблему я делаю, ПРОСТО ИНТЕРЕСНО.<br />
Нет такой функции, что поделаешь, а если есть, значит хорошо и хотел бы знать как она называется.
<br /><br />
Лучше скажи есть или нет, а не засоряй базу hashcode лишними байтами ненужных символов!!!

Comment: нету. наоборот, трафик для сайта делаю, байты жалко было лет 20 назад =)